# Ауто-конвертер из маркапа в html (оно wysiwig для qtextedit) PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, markdown, qtextedit

```
...
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
...
import markdown
...

class QBoard(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QBoard, self).__init__()
        self.textChanged.connect(self.handle)
        self.md = markdown.Markdown()

    def handle(self):
        self.setHtml(self.md.convert(self.toHtml()))
...
```

Это не работает, зависает или maximum recursion depth exceeded (((. Как сделать чтоб пользователь вводил markdown и он конвертировался в html (чтобы сделать setHtml и пользователь видел резульатат)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае сигнал `textChanged` - не подходит.

Попробуйте нажать `Cntl+Z` и `Cntl+X`

````
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import markdown                                     # pip install markdown


class Board(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(Board, self).__init__()
        self._text = text
        self.setText(self._text)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Z and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            self.handle()
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key_X and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            self.setText(self._text)
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def handle(self):
        html = markdown.markdown(self.toPlainText())
        self.setHtml(html)


text = '''# Calculadora en PyQt5

## Descripción:
Es una aplicación *GUI* creada con **PyQt5** y **Python3**, en está *GUI* se manejan todos los aspectos básicos de **PyQt5** para la creación de interfaces. En este proyectos se implementa lo siguiente:

* Uso de **PyQt5**
* Creación de *GUI's* con **PyQt5**
* Modificación de aspectos básicos en **PyQt5** (fuentes, colores, tamaños, posiciones)
* Uso de estilos en *GUI*
* Creación de mensajes y dialogos

## Características:
* Guarda en un archivo *"historial.hist"* todas las operaciones que se han realizado
* Puede utilizar las teclas para manejar más rápido la calculadora:
    * **[0-9.]:** Escribe le caracter presionado
    * **[+ - * / (SHIFT+0)]:** Teclas para operar con los números
    * **[BACKSPACE]:** Borra un caracter del número actual
    * **[N]:** Pone el número actual en negativo

## Versión actual: *1.1*
---

### Requisitos para correr el proyecto:
1. Tener instalado el módulo **PyQt5** en el *entorno virtual (virtualenv)* a utilizar o en *Python* en general.

### Notas:
1. La *GUI* está creada por medio de código, no existe ningún archivo *XML* para modificarlo en el diseñador gráfico.
2. Para instalar **PyQt5** es recomendable que sea con el módulo **pip** de *Python*.

En caso de *Linux* debemos instalar **pip** para *Python3*:
>```sudo apt-get install python3-pip```

Después instalar **PyQt5**:
>```sudo pip3 install pyqt5```

En caso de *Windows*, cuando se instala *Python* trae instalado por defecto el módulo **pip**, solo queda instalar **PyQt5**:
>```pip install pyqt5```
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Board(text)
    w.resize(600, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
````

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @VictorVosMottor я добавил ответ к вашему спящему вопросу, попробуйте.